# Proving that a Finite Field Over Its Prime Field Is Galois

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

> [image: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter6.pdf]

In the above, I don't understand why the author needs to use another theorem to show that $f$ is separable.  Theorem 3.4.5 says that in a finite field, say $F$, the Frobenius automorphism gives us $F = F^p$, entailing that every irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ is separable.  My thinking is, if $E$ exhausts all possible $p^n$ distinct roots of $f$, then $f$ just cannot have repeated roots.  This is pretty much the last statement in the paragraph.  So, was the author being redundant?

Comment: Why can $f$ not have repeated roots if all $p^n$ elements of $E$ are roots of $f$? I don't see how these two are related...

Comment: I agree with Andy Tam: Lagrange shows that $f$ has $p^n$ distinct roots in $E$ and its degree is $p^n$. Hence it must be separable.

Comment: Books are written by living breathing human beings, not by machines. Accordingly, we may find inefficiencies and infelicities, and even (gasp) errors in books, even highly regarded ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct. This is not really needed and you know right away that f is separable. In general, the idea you have outlined is a common and excellent way to show that a polynomial is separable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/524197)

Comment: How does this fail to provide an answer? They asked if they could shortcut the proof, and I said yes.

Comment: I don't remember making this review. Galois theory is not among my favorite subjects neither... Maybe your answer got mixed up with something because it is too short, like a comment.

Comment: Ok, TY .... Just making sure.